# Delete event not emitted

Tags: deepstream.io

I'm using a basic Deepstream setup with RethinkDB, but for some reason the delete event is never emitted when a record is deleted?

```
var x = window.deepstream.record.getRecord('test1');
x.subscribe(function(){
    console.log('was deleted')
})
window.setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('deleting');
    x.delete();
},2000);
```

The "something happened" text never ouputs... Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like subscribe does not actually listen for the delete event, I needed to specifically do:

```
x.on('delete', function(){
    console.log('was deleted')
})
```